# I can not read entire text file on android

Tags: android, file, bufferedreader

Could you please help me that I can not read entire text file.

I could only read around 100 lines from text file.

text size = 61535

The code is as following.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
path = path + "/testFile.txt";
StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
char[] buf = new char[1024];
int numRead=0;

while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1)
{
    String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
    fileData.append(readData);
}

reader.close();
```

I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Any exceptions (look at Logcat)?

Comment: and what happens after 100 lines????

Comment: @user2445150 can you post the xml file???

Comment: @Michael Butscher Hi there, There is no exception at all.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini nothing happened. no more characters in String.

Comment: @Metalhead1247 You can test it with any text files.

Comment: It seems your problem is not in the posted code snippet

Comment: @Michael Butscher Have you tested this? and there is nothing wrong with that? Are you albe to read entire text file on android? :( Then, What is wrong with me..:(

Comment: @user2445150 is there a scroll view in you xml?

Comment: @user2445150 I haven't tested it but I think I have enough experience to see such an error in a small code snippet. It happens often that the bug isn't where one expects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    File yourFile = new File("Path");
    InputStream input= new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile), 8086); 
    String str = convertStreamToString(input);
```

Method for convert InputStrem to String.

```
 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But I've got the same result. only around 100 lines I got. Could you Please let me know another way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this answer or the original code. Either the file you have is only 100 lines or it's not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Yes, I have found that there is nothing wrong with that code. something wrong with Log..

Answer (score -1):

If  you have not used **Scrollview** in you xml file then that might be the problem you are facing!!

Have you used **Scrollview** ?

Please  post the respective Xml file of your activity.